# ReDash to Google Sheets using Google Script - How do I add the date at the end?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use the following Google script to add data from Redash, then add the current date at the end.  Where could I add a `var now = new Date();` to input the date on the last row?

The desired outcome is the following.  A-C is the data I'm successfully already pulling from Redash, but I want to add the current date.  The date will always be in F if that helps.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lfu9jk06j0fduo8/Screenshot%202020-05-20%2018.44.26.png?dl=0

Thank you for your help!

```
//FUNCTION FOR GETTING DATA FROM REDASH QUERIES
function getapidata(response, sheetname) {
  var array1 = response.getContentText(); //Store data from redash into this variable
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var iLen = array1.length;
  var i = 0;
  var stringvalue1 = "";
  var s1 = "";
  var num1 = 1;
  var num2 = 1;
  var noheader = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < iLen; i++) {
    var j = i;
    do {
      s1 = array1[j];
      if (s1 == ",") {
        if (noheader == 1)
          noheader = 1;
        else
          sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + num1, num2).setValue(stringvalue1);
        num1 = 0;
        num2++;
        stringvalue1 = "";
      } else
        stringvalue1 = stringvalue1 + s1;
      j++;
    } while (s1 != "\n")
    if (noheader == 1)
      noheader = 1;
    else
      sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + num1, num2).setValue(stringvalue1);
    noheader = 2;
    num1 = 1;
    num2 = 1;
    stringvalue1 = "";
    i = j - 1;
  }
}

function getfromRedash() {
  //Current SHR (Max Preps)
  var redashapi = "API"; //Storing Redash API Value.
  var sheetname = "SHEETTITLE"; //Assign your sheetname(where you would want data to be imported) to this variable
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(redashapi, {
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  }); //Storing Redash Cached Query result in this variable.
  Logger.log(response.getContentText()); //If any error, error to be logged
  getapidata(response, sheetname); //Call function for writing data in google sheets
  //The 5 lines of code above can be repeated for multiple sheets in a single google spreadsheet file. For. Eg. If you have 5 different sheets in a single google worksheet, you can just copy paste the above lines of code, and just change the variable “redashapi” so as to make calls to the appropriate redash queries.
}

//THIS FUNCTION IS TO MAKE A NEW MENU IN GOOGLE SHEETS
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('MENU')
    .addItem('Get Data from Redash', 'getfromRedash')
    .addToUi();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you row number addressing is a bit confusing, cause sheet.getLastRow() would change every time you add values after the last row, but you can write something like

```
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + num1, 6).setValue(new Date());
```

to insert date. You can refer other answers, like

[How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

for date formatting.